# flutter json decode and file append not working on second run

Tags: json, flutter

I was wondering if someone could help? I'm trying to load a file with json content, decode it, convert to a model/object add another element.

The way I'm trying to do this is as follows:

*Flow 1: Check file exists = true -> return file object -> decode string to json -> convert to model/object -> add element -> back to json -> to string -> save file.*

*Flow 2: Check file exists = false -> create file -> add a json template -> return file object -> decode string to json -> convert to model/object -> add element -> back to json -> to string -> save file.*

This is working on the first run (flow 1), it'll create the file, add the template then add the first new element. However, when I run it a second time (flow 2), I always get an throwback.

As we speak with the code below, the error is:

```
E/flutter (13140): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'
E/flutter (13140): #0      FileController.writeSingleResponseToFile (package:reefcommander/controllers/FileController.dart:33:39)
E/flutter (13140): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (13140):
```

This is the code I'm using.

**FileController.dart**

```
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:reefcommander/models/ReadingsData.dart';
import 'package:reefcommander/models/SingleDataReqResponse.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

class FileController {
  static String date = DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(DateTime.now());
  static String template =
      '{"name": "_NAME_", "friendlyName": "_FNAME_", "results": []}';
  static final Map<String, String> nameDefenitions = {
    'ec': 'EC',
    'ph': 'pH',
    'atoDayRate': 'Evap Rate',
    'sumpTemp': 'Temp (sump)',
    'tankTemp': 'Temp (tank)'
  };

  static Future<File> checkFileExists(String type) async {
    readFile(type);
    final Directory? directory = Platform.isAndroid
        ? await getExternalStorageDirectory() //FOR ANDROID
        : await getApplicationSupportDirectory();
    final String filename = '${directory!.path}/${date}_$type.json';
    final File file = File(filename);
    return file;
  }

  static writeSingleResponseToFile(SingleDataReqResponse resp) async {
    final File file = await checkFileExists(resp.name.toString());

    var r = Map<String, dynamic>.from(jsonDecode(await file.readAsString()));
    print(r.runtimeType);
    ReadingsData existingdata = ReadingsData.fromJson(r[0]);

    //ReadingsData existingdata =
    //  r.map<ReadingsData>((json) => ReadingsData.fromJson(json));
    print(existingdata);
    existingdata.results!.add(Results(stamp: resp.stamp, value: resp.value));
    print('DATA: ${existingdata.toJson().toString()}');
    file.writeAsString(jsonEncode(existingdata.toJson().toString()));
  }

  static Future<void> deleteFile(String type) async {
    try {
      final Directory? directory = Platform.isAndroid
          ? await getExternalStorageDirectory() //FOR ANDROID
          : await getApplicationSupportDirectory();
      final String filename = '${directory!.path}/${date}_$type.json';
      final File file = File(filename);

      if (file.existsSync()) {
        await file.delete();
      } else {}
    } catch (e) {
      // Error in getting access to the file.
    }
  }

  static Future<String> readFile(String type) async {
    String text = '';
    try {
      final Directory? directory = Platform.isAndroid
          ? await getExternalStorageDirectory() //FOR ANDROID
          : await getApplicationSupportDirectory();
      final String filename = '${directory!.path}/${date}_$type.json';
      final File file = File(filename);

      if (file.existsSync()) {
        text = await file.readAsString();
      } else {
        file.create(recursive: true);
        String tempbase = template;
        String write = tempbase
            .replaceAll('_NAME_', type.toString())
            .replaceAll('_FNAME_', nameDefenitions[type]!);
        await file.writeAsString(write);

        text = await file.readAsString();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("Read error");
    }
    return text;
  }
}
```

**ReadingsData.dart**

```
import 'dart:convert';

class ReadingsData {
  String? name;
  String? friendlyName;
  List<Results>? results;

  ReadingsData(
      {required this.name, required this.friendlyName, required this.results});

  ReadingsData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name = json['name'];
    friendlyName = json['friendlyName'];
    if (json['results'] != null) {
      results = <Results>[];
      json['results'].forEach((v) {
        results!.add(Results.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['name'] = name;
    data['friendlyName'] = friendlyName;
    if (results != null) {
      data['results'] = results!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Results {
  String? stamp;
  String? value;

  Results({required this.stamp, required this.value});

  Results.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    stamp = json['stamp'];
    value = json['value'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['stamp'] = stamp;
    data['value'] = value;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Test code

```
FileController.writeSingleResponseToFile(
        SingleDataReqResponse(name: "test", stamp: "10:22:00", value: "2222"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else in my situation, I've resolved it. Solution below.

```
  static writeSingleResponseToFile(SingleDataReqResponse resp) async {
    final File file = await checkFileExists(resp.name.toString());

    ReadingsData existingdata =
        ReadingsData.fromJson(jsonDecode(await file.readAsString()));

    existingdata.results!.add(Results(stamp: resp.stamp, value: resp.value));

    file.writeAsString(jsonEncode(existingdata.toJson()));
  }
```